# What happens if an illegal substance or an item that belongs to my housemate is caught in my house?

Tags: criminal-law, tenant, firearms, drugs, turkey

I am 31 years old and still live with my family in Turkey. And I don't want to live with my parents anymore. I must move out of the house of my parents. My parents also approve and support my idea about moving.

Because of being able to afford living expenses, I'll have to live with a housemate. And the rental contract is going to be on behalf of me.

But a friend of mine told me some negative possibilities about living with housemates. He says that if an illegal substance(like narcotic drugs) or an illegal item(like an unregistered gun) is caught in my house, I'll get into trouble even if the illegal thing doesn't belong to me.

Please help about this issue. What are your opinions?

Comment: You need to make a proper housesharing contract if that's a thing in Turkey... So that damages and al. will be cvered under both of you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In the US, criminal prosecution is possible if you possess illegal drugs. Presence of drugs in a house that you own or reside in it not per se illegal, so the prosecution would have to prove, beyond reasonable doubt, that it is in fact *your* drugs. If it was in someone else's room, the argument would be much harder to make.

[turkey](/questions/tagged/turkey)

Drug law in Turkey are much stiffer in the US. In addition, "beyond reasonable doubt" is not a requirement for conviction, so the burden would be on you to prove that it was not your drugs. This is a matter that should be discussed with a Turkish criminal defense attorney, since the Turkish justice system is not the same as common law or EU systems.

Comment: But at least, can we say that fingertips or dna samples are required to accuse a person for illegal things?(even in a country having strict law)

Comment: No, not even in the US. Drugs in your bedroom will likely get you convicted, even lacking fingerprints or dna.

Comment: If the question is literally "will I be in trouble", then the answer is "quite possibly". Having police on your case is trouble. Having to go to court, even if you are found "not guilty' in the end, is trouble. And you can be incorrectly found guilty, that's a lot of trouble.

Comment: An additional caveat for the United States is civil forfeiture of assets. *Even if no one is arrested*, the police can confiscate any money or items they claim to be associated with the drug use, and it is on you to sue the police to get your stuff back (and you have to pay for your own legal bills). It's... not a good thing, but it is the law of the land in many states.